# How do I move on to the next element in my list based on some condition satisfied in a function I have called?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def check_if_number_is_5(x):
try:
    #some code
except Exception as e:
    #some code
```

```
for x in some_list:
   #Some code
   check_if_number_is_5(x)
   #Rest of the code
```

Basically, I want to move on to the next element in my list if that condition is satisfied and I don't want `#Rest of the code` to run.

Is there anyway to do this without returning a boolean value and having another conditional statement. **I have explored doing this with an exception but the problem is the exception is being caught with by the except block of the function.**

Comment: Google the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the `continue` statement, to move on to the next iteration, but you need a triggerer, for that, there is 2 ways :

- the `boolean` one

  ```py
  def check_if_number_is_5(x):
      try:
          # some code
          return True
      except Exception as e:
          # some code
          return False

  some_list = []
  for x in some_list:
      # Some code
      if check_if_number_is_5(x):
          continue
      # Rest of the code
  ```
- the `exception` one

  ```py
  def check_if_number_is_5(x):
      try:
          # some code
          pass
      except Exception as e:
          # some code
          raise Exception()

  some_list = []
  for x in some_list:
      # Some code
      try:
          check_if_number_is_5(x)
      except:
          continue
      # Rest of the code
  ```

Answer (score 0):

so the function would look like somewhat this:
don't catch error in the function

```html
def check_if_number_is_not_5(x):
    if x==5:
      return False
    return True
```

In the code call the function and check return value then use the `break` to breakout of loop.

```html
some_list = []
for x in some_list:
    # code
    if check_if_number_is_not_5(x):
        break
    # code
```